# An unambiguous word for when we, in the middle of doing things, want to refer to the thing we will do at the end?

Tags: word-usage

After several comments on a paper, in this comment I want to refer to the comment I will made at the end of all comments. So I say:

> Please see my last comment.

But "last comment" also means the previous comment.

Words such as "final", "ultimate", and "latest" have connotations that make me think they are not the best choice. "final" and "ultimate" both have the connotation of being the conclusion, and "latest" has the problem I mentioned about "last".

What is your suggestion?

Comment: It seems odd that you ask the reader to skip ahead in your argument, rather than refer back to something you previously said.  What is the context of this -- what are you trying to say that you would organize your argument this way?

Comment: @Andrew Comments are related. I want to relate them to each other. So, for example there are in all 20 comments. In comment number 10 I want to refer to the reader to the comment number 20.

Comment: I guess it seems more logical to refer back to comment 10 from comment 20, than to do it the other way around.   But if you feel it's necessary, then I would explicitly number your comments, and refer to them by number.

Comment: Wondering if using footnotes would help? Reference, here: http://www.plagiarism.org/article/what-are-footnotes